# React Native communicate between 2 android devices

Tags: react-native, bluetooth, communication

I'm using react native to create a simple app that essentially allows 2 android phones to communicate. These devices will always be next to each other, and will only communicate with one another. As I was doing some research it seems that bluetooth would be the best approach, connect the 2 phones and have them send messages. However, I haven't found a working `react-native` library. It seems that classic bluetooth (serial) would be the optimal approach and not BLE. I tried libraries that support classic bluetooth such as `react-native-bluetooth-cross-platform`, `react-native-bluetooth-serial`, and `react-native-bluetooth-serial-next`. However, none seem to work properly (they seem fairly outdated). The devices pair, but don't connect in order to send/read messages. Is there another form of secure communication I can use to have these devices communicate with one another? If bluetooth is the best form, is there any better serial bluetooth libraries out there?

Edit: I was also looking into using wifi p2p, however it seems like overkill since it's only these 2 devices that will communicate to each other and no other device. Also if I do use wifi p2p would it be possible to only have 2 devices communicate (i.e no other device can eavesdrop or send messages to the 2). Also, these devices will be stationary and pretty close, so if there is a way for 2-way communication via a cable, that will also work.